# Why is my directory getting quotes around it when created?

Tags: filenames

I create a directory called `bob@example.com/`

I wanted to use this email address as the directory name - I know - not a good idea for many reasons - but lets assume this is a very temporary directory that I delete seconds later :)

I give the command

```
mkdir bob@example.com
```

However when I check the directory I see it actually created it with quotes around it.

```
...
'bob@example.com`
...
```

I then found this is due to the `@`

What are the rules for special characters in directory names and how does the system decide to quote them

Comment: I'm on Mint and can't replicate?

Comment: Could you copy and paste the output from `ls` into your question? Or does it really end with a backtick?

Comment: Is your `ls` aliased to `ls --quoting-style=locale`? That's the only way I can replicate it. (although I get surrounding unicode quotes, not single quotes or backticks)

Comment: @jeff, yes it is and i think that is indeed part of the issue. ty

Comment: 'cos `/usr/bin/ls` doesn't have the issue.  My ls is an alias to `alias ls='ls -F --color=al'`

Comment: @Michael I don't understand the connection to `-F` or `--color=al(ways)`, so I posted my guess (the quoting-style) in an Answer.

Comment: The presence of quotes is a really irritating non-backwards-compatible change to the `ls` command. You can revert it with `export QUOTING_STYLE=literal`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just the way that `ls` *displays* the name, and does not mean that the name contains literal quotes.

If your `ls` is aliased to use `--quoting-style=locale`, that would produce:

```
‘bob@example.com’
```

... with unicode "LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK" and "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK" characters surrounding the filename(s).